# Provided 2..N Vector in 2D Space, what would be Scalar of each Vector to match target Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Provided from 2 to N Vectors in 2D space. What would be the Scalar of each Vector to match the target Vector?

Eg: Given **A: {X=1,Y=0}** and **B: {X=0,Y=1}** and **Target: {X=2,Y=1}** what would be the scalar of each vector individually to match the target Vector.

```
A * X + B * Y = Target;
```

in this case, it's easy to calculate for this given target.

```
{X=1,Y=0} * 2 + {X=0,Y=1} * 1 = {X=2,Y=1}
```

but given that there might be more than 2 vectors, and the fact that vectors can be at any angle relative to each other makes this more complex, and cannot grasp how to notate it. Note that the Sum of each scalar should be the lowest possible (as close to 0 as possible) to achieve the target vector.

Harder example:

```
Given:
A: {X=0.44,Y=1.1}
B: {X=1.27,Y=-0.3}
C: {X=-0.3,Y=0.0}
T: {X=0.76,Y=0.7}

Calculate:
A * X + B * Y + C * Z = T
```

My goal is to write this in a C# programming language to calculate the thrust vector for velocity cancelation given N thrusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and cannot grasp how to notate it.

I can help you with that! What you are describing is basically linear algebra and [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). I will denote vectors with lowercase latin letters, scalars with greek letters and matrices with uppercase latin letters. Your first example:

Given vectors $a=(1,0),b=(0,1)$ and $t=(2,1)$, find $\mu,\nu$ such that $t=\mu a+\nu b$.

can be re-written with matrix notation as

Given a matrix $M=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\vdots&\vdots\\a&b\\\vdots&\vdots\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, find a vector $v=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\mu\\\nu\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ such that $Mv=t$.

In this case, the solution can be found by inverting the matrix $M$: we find $v=M^{-1}t=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Now on to the second example:

Given vectors $a=(0.44, 1.1), b=(1.27, -0.3), c=(-0.3, 0.0)$ and $t=(0.76, 0.7)$, find $\mu,\nu,\eta$ such that $\mu a+\nu b+ \eta c = t$

Can be re-written in matrix notation as:

Given a matrix $M=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a&b&c\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.44&1.27&-0.3\\1.1&-0.3&0.0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, find a vector $v=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\mu\\\nu\\\eta\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ such that $Mv=t=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.76\\0.7\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

In this case, there are many possible $v$ for which $Mv=t$, which might be why this problem seems complicated. In general, you can calculate the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) $\mathrm{ker}(M)$, and find *some* $\mu_0,\nu_0$ (like above) such that $\mu_0a+\nu_0b=t$. Then for *any* $(\mu,\nu,\eta)\in\mathrm{ker}(M)$, you also have that $(\mu_0+\mu)a+(\nu_0+\nu)b+\eta c=t$.

In this specific example, we find $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\mu_0\\\nu_0\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.44&1.27\\1.1&-0.3\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.76\\0.7\end{smallmatrix}\right)\approx \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.730543\\0.345324\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\mathrm{ker}(M)\approx\mathrm{Span}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0.0574422\\0.210621\\0.975879\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, so you can take any real number $\lambda$, and you would have

$(0.730543+\lambda 0.0574422)a + (0.345324 + \lambda 0.210621)b + 0.97587 c = t$.

The particulars on how you want to choose $\lambda$ are up to you. You seem to say something about minimalisation ("Note that the Sum of each scalar should be the lowest possible (as close to 0 as possible) to achieve the target vector.") but I do not fully understand what you mean.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you! The solution at glance make sense but I need to deep dive to understand this! I will accept the answer once I get better grasp of it and test it works.
About the sum of scalars, I think I will manage to go from this as there is plentiful of information to go off.

Comment: Calculating this inverse of kernel of the matrix gave always the correct result for the matrix. So this gave me an idea, to calculate the inverse of the whole matrix. Using Pseudo Inverse and then multiplying by the targeting vector works like a charm! Thank you again @student91!

Comment: I've never heard of the pseudo-inverse before, I learned something today :D